# Type hinting for objects in instance of child class of UserList

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Working with `Python 3.11.1` and `Pycharm 2023.1.2`

I wrote custom class `MyList` for storing lists using `collections.UserList`. And one more class `ListOfUsers` which inheriting of `MyList`.

```
from collections import UserList


class User:
    def very_useful_method(self):
        pass


class MyList(UserList):
    pass


class ListOfUsers(MyList[User]):
    pass


users = [User() for _ in range(3)]
list_of_users = ListOfUsers(users)
for user in list_of_users:
    user.very_
```

But, when i typing `user.very_` don't see auto completion helper for `very_useful_method` method of `User`. In other words: IDE does not know which objects `ListOfUsers` storing inside `data` attribute.

I tested it without inheriting from parent class and it works fine, but how to make it work with nested classes?

Comment: You need `class MyList(UserList[_T])`, where `_T = typing.TypeVar('_T')`. Being generic is not implicitly inherited: in your implementation `MyList` is equivalent to `UserList[typing.Any]` (essentially `list[Any]`), and no further specification is possible.

Comment: @SUTerliakov It is working and answering question! Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `i` is a string, so it has no `very_useful_method` of `class User`.

```
from collections import UserList


class User:
    def very_useful_method(self):
        print(1)
        pass


class MyList(UserList):
    pass


class ListOfUsers(MyList[User]):
    pass


foo = [User() for _ in range(3)]
bar = ListOfUsers(foo)
for i in bar:
    i.very_useful_method()
```

Comment: I downvote, because this obviously doesn't answer the question - `__init__` can interpret these strings in any way it wants, and the question is about `[User]` part being effectively ignored in class definition.

Comment: I made a mistake and will change question for others to better understand question. Anyway @SUTerliakov already answered in comments